# How to pass C# objects into another form and make it the title of this form?

Tags: c#, winforms, accessor, showdialog

I'm working with two forms. One is a login form and the other is a detail form. I'm trying to pass the objects that were obtained from login such as username and id# to the details, so that when the enter button is pressed, the details form loads with the greeting, "Hello [username + id#]! at the title bar of the form.

This is what I have started---

Form1:

```
public partial class Login : Form
{
        //Auto-Impl Properties
        private Details de = new Details();
private void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            GetInputs();
            //validate inputs
            de.ShowDialog(); //display the 2nd form
}

2nd form:

public partial class Details : Form
{
        public string Fname { get; set; }
        public string Lname { get; set; }
        public string Unum { get; set; }



        public Details()
        {
            InitializeComponent();           
        }

        private void Details_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
}
```

***I also want to indicate that the Program.cs is set to run the Login***

This code loads the 2nd form after the enter button is pressed but of course the objects from form1 is not passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you aware that you can add parameters to the form's constructor?

```
public Details(string userName)
{
    InitializeComponent();           
    // set the title here
}
```

You can create the Details form *after* you got login data and pass the name in the constructor:

```
GetInputs();
// validate inputs
de = new Details("name");
de.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: I supposed that is one way? Is there a way to use a tag? I would need to implement this using accessors as noted above.

Comment: Well yes.. `de.Tag = "name"` and then from inside the Form put the string from the tag into the title, why not.. I personally prefer passing defined arguments. Safer and clearer

Comment: @Pinkfit Why don't you simply use `de.Text = "name"`? If you're planning to use a property just use [the one that is planned for that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.text?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: To fit your specific needs `de.Text = $"Hello [{username}  {id}]!";` (using [C# 6 string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)) or `de.Text = string.Format("Hello [{0} {1}]!", username, id);` (using [string.Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Format_System_String_System_Object_System_Object_))